# Why isn't Heroku serving images using Laravel linked storage?

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

When I run my Laravel app locally it shows images but when I deploy it on Heroku images don't dynamically display from my storage folder.

Here is an example code snippet where I try to show an image:

```
<img src="{{url(('storage/'.$Post -> image))}}" height="60px" height="60px" alt="Image"/>
```

The server responds with Failed to load resource: 404 (Not Found):

[image]

Why isn't this working, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the source URL of the broken image, and what should it actually be?

Answer (score 3):

Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) will lose any changes made to it (e.g. uploaded files, or symlinks created via `artisan storage:link`) the next time your dyno restarts. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day).

Instead, you should use a non-local [driver](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#driver-prerequisites) for file storage, e.g. the Amazon S3 driver. Heroku [recommends this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) in their official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you executed `php artisan storage:link` in you host or made simlink to your storage folder

Comment: yes they perfectly show in my localhost but when i apply this command on heroku they did't show my images from public folder.

Comment: nice,so run this command in your heroku bash
`heroku run /app/php/bin/php /app/www/artisan storage:link`

Comment: or this
`heroku run bash`

`php artisan storage:link`

Comment: `artisan storage:link` won't work as expected on Heroku due to its ephemeral filesystem.